# linked list cpp. cstring not returning desired value

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, c-strings

So, the issue essentially is in findEl function. when I call it, it doesnt actually return the node i asked for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct gameElements {
    char element[50];
    char power[50];
    int coordinates[2][2];
    int pcoordinates[3][2];
    gameElements *next;
};
using p_elements = gameElements*;
p_elements test(p_elements &p, char element[50], int parr[3][2], int x, int y) {

    p_elements newEl = new gameElements;
    strcpy(newEl->element, element);
    newEl->coordinates[0][0] = y;
    newEl->coordinates[0][1] = x;
    newEl->coordinates[1][0] = y;
    newEl->coordinates[1][1] = x + 1;
    newEl->next = NULL;
    for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            newEl->pcoordinates[n][i] = parr[n][i];
        }
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        p = newEl;

    } else {
        p_elements tmp = p;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = newEl;



    }
    return p;
}
p_elements findEl(p_elements &p,char element[50]){
    p_elements x=p;
    if(x==NULL){
        return NULL;

    }else if(strcmp(x->element,element)==0){
        return x;
    }else{
        while(x!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(x->element,element)==0){
                return x;
            }else x = x->next;

        }return NULL;
    }


}
int main() {
    p_elements elements = new gameElements;
    elements=NULL;
    char p[50] = "Power";
    char a[50] = "Artifact";
    int doorTonlvl[3][2] = { { 5, 96 }, { 6, 96 }, { 7, 96 } };
    int vDoor[3][2] = { { 11, 54 }, { 12, 54 }, { 13, 54 } };
    elements = test(elements, a, doorTonlvl, 4, 3);
    elements = test(elements, p, vDoor, 57, 8);

    p_elements artifact = findEl(elements, a);
    cout << artifact->element << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This current code return nothing when I'm trying to find "char a[50]", while if i try to find "char p[50]" it returns a.
ps: I'm forced to use string.h library due to assignment

EDIT:
added includes.
Current code return nothing(the program gets executed without printing anything in the terminal). Expected artifact->element which in this case is "char a"

I think the issue could be in test(..) function, in this case my linked list has only 2 nodes. when I try find the first node by using findEl() it doesnt print anything in the terminal, but instead of if i to try find second node by using same function and just swapping parameter findEl(elements,a) to findEl(elements,p) it prints out first node (a) rather than second, which is what i was looking for in this case)

Apparently the issue was in the while loop in findEl(..), it was checking if the next node was null, therefore exist whlie loop if true

Comment: What have you learned using your debugger?

Comment: its a little confusing to hide a pointer behind a type alias. Passing that type by non-const reference when a `const` ref or simply pass by value would be ok adds more confusion on top

Comment: Your code could barely be called C++, it's almost entirely plain C.

Comment: why leave out the includes from your code? I mean you even mention it in the title but then in the code it is missing. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: fwiw, in C++ the header is called `cstring`. `string.h` is the C header

Comment: And please include output and expected output in the question. Its not clear what "This current code return nothing " means. It returns `0`.

Comment: strings in C++ should be modeled using std::string, not as "C" style arrays of chars. You also don't need to write your own list there is std::list, but probably a std::vector of game elements would suffice too. My advice learn some more C++ and start again.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use std::list and/or vectors. It's a college assignment. I'm only allowed to use cstring as "external" library

Comment: @helper I think (I've only briefly looked) is that the error is that `strcmp(x->element,element)` should be `strcmp(x->element,element)==0` (two different places). `strcmp` returns **zero** if the two strings are equal, not true as you seem to be assuming.

Comment: I've already tried **strcmp(x->element,element)==0** and it still doesn't fix the issue . and yeh, I can't really talk to college cus we, students, already tried. They want this way so we find different ways of working stuff out rather than just use "pre-made stuff" @john

Comment: @helper OK, well it's perfectly possible that you code has multiple bugs, and more than one change is needed. Nevertheless if you are testing for string equality then `strcmp(x,y) == 0` is the correct code, so make that change. I'll take a closer look, see if I can spot any other errors

Comment: @helper This is a bug `while(x->next!=NULL){` it should be `while(x!=NULL)`. Your version will skip checking the last node in the list.

Comment: yeh this last one fixes the issue, lol. Didnt notice. Thank you very much indeed @john

Comment: @helper `strcpy(newEl->element, element);` -- I know you claim this is a college assignment, but really, the `std::string` has been *officially* part of C++ for close to **25 years now**.  How long is a college going to hold onto not using it?  It's like someone teaching a course on how to fix flatscreen TV's and then requiring you know what vacuum tubes are.